# heroku pg:push remote database is not empty?

Tags: heroku

I am trying to pg:push my database to heroku server but 
still getting the remote database is not empty error although
I am resetting/ the db with pg:reset

```
heroku pg:reset remote_database_name
heroku pg:push dev_database remote_database
```

Still getting the error.
For the remote database name I am using the name my-database-7121::pink

Comment: Are you doing the original push in this format? heroku pg:push mylocaldb DATABASE_URL --app sushi

Comment: Yes I even create a new app and nothing have changed.

Answer (score 1):

I had this problem and it took me a while to solve.

The trick is making sure Postgres is set up properly. To check that it is, type the following into your Terminal:

```
$ which psql
```

If you're on a Mac and you're using Postgres.app, this should return something the directory where Postgres.app can be found, e.g.:

```
$ /Applications/Postgres.app/Contents/Versions/9.3/bin/psql
```

If the 'which psql' command returns nothing, restart the Terminal and type in the following:

```
$ export PATH=$PATH:/Applications/Postgres.app/Contents/Versions/9.3/bin
```

Check that this command now works (i.e. returns a directory):

```
$ which psql
```

If it does, you should be able to carry on with the 'heroku pg:reset' and 'heroku pg:push' - only this time it will (hopefully) work